# What do gm and mk stand for in gmtime() and mktime()?

Tags: c++, linux, naming-conventions

I tried searching it online, but hard to find any relevant answer since the result page is overwhelmed by mk/gmtime function documentation.

Comment: "greenwich mean" and "make". e.g. generate a UTC time, and MaKe a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gmtime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html) - [*GMT (UTC)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) time

> Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) originally referred to the mean solar time
>   at the Royal Observatory in Greenwich, London, which later became
>   adopted as a global time standard. It is for the most part the same as
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

[mktime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html) - *make* time

> convert broken-down time into time since the Epoc